# how to create dataframe for loops in python

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Am scrapping data from a website, all the data is in the table. I want to create a dataframe for all the table information.

I am using the below code to get the table information.

```
all_table_info = html_soup.find('table', class_ = "views-table cols-4")---to get all the table info

for name in all_table_info.find_all('td',class_ = "views-field views-field-field-lastname active"):

    print (name.text)

for organization in all_table_info.find_all('td', class_ = "views-field views-field-field-employer") :

    print (organization.text)
```

i have a requirement to creat a dataframe which create 2 coulmns for name and organisation.

```
name Organization

abcv fgvf

dfdf ghgjh

dfgdg hgjh

fgfg hkh
```

Is there is any way to do this.

Comment: Is there any example site your are trying to scrape with those class names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track. What you need is only a step away. First, put all your data into lists.

```
names = []
orgs = []

for name in all_table_info.find_all('td', 
           class_="views-field views-field-field-lastname active"):
    names.append(name.text.strip() if name.text else None)

for organization in all_table_info.find_all('td', 
           class_="views-field views-field-field-employer"):
    orgs.append(organization.text.strip() if organization.text else None)
```

Now, create your dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : names, 'Org' : orgs})
```

Comment: is there is anyway to strip the data , the result is like this                                                                   0 \n\n\n\n \n\n\n Mr. \n Rex \n D. \n Adams  \n\...   
1   \n\n\n\n \n\n\n Mr. \n William  \n S. \n Allen...   
2   \n\n\n\n \n\n\n Mr. \n Lucien \n Alziari  \n\n...

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, is the is anyway to strip the \n\n\n\n

Comment: @K.Sanjay Is the data in a dataframe? If yes, please vote on, and mark my answer accepted and open a new question, since that needs another answer. Paste your current dataframe output in the _new_ question.

Comment: I have tried this   :                                                                                                    for name in all_table_info.find_all('td', 
           class_="views-field views-field-field-lastname active"):
    names.append(name.text)
    names = names.strip('\n')                                                                                                                 But I getting error 'list object has no attribute strip'

Comment: @K.Sanjay you’re doing it wrong. If you read my previous comment, I already explained what you should do. Please listen to me. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for that I haven't seen that comment